# How to check and store particular time-period in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, timedelta

I have to store restaurants on my table in the Django model. Each restaurant has its opening and closing time. For each I have to check if a particular restaurant is open or not with respect to the current time a user search for available restaurants.

Comment: where is your model ?

Comment: and? you need to show us your models right!

Comment: We have no information but considering your question [DateTimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the comparison, and a very simple case, you would do something like this:

```
 is_open = user_request_time > restaurant.open and user_request_time < restaruant.close
```

But this is probably too simple. Restaurants are open different hours on different days.

So you might try giving a `Schedule` object to each restaurant:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    sunday_open = TimeField()
    sunday_close = TimeFiled()
    ....
```

Then make a class method in Restaurant:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule)
    ....

    def is_open(self, time=None)
        if not time:
            time = timezone.now()
        today = time.weekday()
        if today == 0:
            open = self.schedule.sunday_open
            close = self.schedule.sunday_close
        elif today == 1:
             ....

        return time > open and time < close
```

This is where I think I would start with something like this.